# Creating new function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to create new jQuery function i try to write some codes.
I want to know is my code valid?

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/HGX2t/)

here is my code

```
$.fn.hitme = function(){
  return this.each(function() {
    if (this.hitme == 'String') this.hitme = alert('you\'ve hitted me!');
  });
};
$('.round').hitme('why?');
```

HTML code

```
<div class='foo'>
    <h1>Here!!</h1>
    <div class='round'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's valid, but it doesn't make a lot of sense. `alert` doesn't return any value, and `this.hitme` is most likely not defined on the DOM element, so `this.hitme == 'String'` will always be `false`.

Comment: @Felix Kling why `this.hitme` not defined on the DOM element?

Comment: Because the DOM API is well defined and such a property simply doesn't exist: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-745549614

Comment: what do you think now my [**code**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/HGX2t/1/) make a sense ?

Comment: U invoked with 'why?', Bt haven't taken anywhere. I think its typeof(this.hitme)=='String'

Comment: Well, `this` is a DOM element. It will never by of type `String` (which should probably `string`, but it doesn't matter either way). So  `typeof(this) == 'String'` will always be `false` again. If you'd properly explain what you are trying to achieve, we could help you better. If you just want to learn how to extend jQuery, please read its documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/.

Comment: @Felix Kling I wanted to create jQuery extend like click or alert. I wanted if inside of `hitme` is string then alert `you have hitted me` for just learning jquery extend. thanx

Comment: You might want to have a look at jQuery's `.data` method if you want to store arbitrary data on DOM elements: http://api.jquery.com/data/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$.fn.hitme = function(item){
  return this.each(function() {
      if (typeof(item) == 'string') alert('you\'ve hit me!')
  });
};
$('.round').hitme('why?');
```